# How to make application that suport both portrait and landscape in iOS

Tags: ios6, landscape-portrait

I'm creating an iOS application which should be supported both landscape and portrait. So I have used 2 views for these 2 orientations. But now the problem is I don't know how to connect `IBoutlets` to the file's owner. Can't we use one `IBOutlet` set to both modes. I haven't done  any application which supported both modes. Please any one can tell me how can I fixed this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this according to this way. I created 2 views and defined seperate IBOutlets set. When change the orientation I assigned the values in one mode to other mode's outlet's values. This did in `(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification`

`

```
 -(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
```

{

```
UIDeviceOrientation newOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (newOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationUnknown && newOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp && newOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown)
{
    if (orientation != newOrientation)
    {
        //ORIENTATION HAS CHANGED
        NSLog(@"Changed Orientation");

        // Do orientation logic
        if (
            ((newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) &&
            ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
            )
        {
            NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape");
            self.orientationMode=@"landscape";
            self.txtInsidernameLandscape.text=self.txtInsiderName.text;
            self.txtCompanynameLandscape.text=self.txtCompanyName.text;
            self.txtAddressLandscape.text=self.txtAddress.text;
            self.txtPhoneLandscape.text=self.txtTelephone.text;
            self.txtEmailLandscape.text=self.txtEmail.text;

            // Clear the current view and insert the orientation specific view.
            [self clearCurrentView];
            [self.view insertSubview:mainLandscapeView atIndex:0];

            //Copy object states between views
            //SomeTextControlL.text = SomeTextControlP.text;
        }
        else if (
                 ((newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) &&
                 ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
                 )
        {
            NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Portrait");
            self.orientationMode=@"portrait";
            self.txtInsiderName.text=self.txtInsidernameLandscape.text;
            self.txtCompanyName.text=self.txtCompanynameLandscape.text;
            self.txtAddress.text=self.txtAddressLandscape.text;
            self.txtPhoneLandscape.text=self.txtPhoneLandscape.text;
            self.txtEmail.text=self.txtEmailLandscape.text;

            // Clear the current view and insert the orientation specific view.
            [self clearCurrentView];
            [self.view insertSubview:mainPortraitView atIndex:0];

            //Copy object states between views
            //SomeTextControlP.text = SomeTextControlL.text;
        }
        orientation = newOrientation;
    }

}
```

}
`